# How to use make sure scrapy is downloaded correctly?

Tags: scrapy

I have scrapy downloaded in anaconda and I am trying to open it inside the command prompt and I am getting the message "'scrapy' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file', can anyone tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: Downloading scrapy is not enough, you have to install it

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have used `conda install scrapy` to install the package.

Then the only reason is: you did not add `/path/to/conda/Scripts` (E.g. C:\Anaconda2\Scripts) to your `PATH`.

This results in you cannot find `scrapy`, or you can use the full path something like `/path/to/conda/Scripts/scrapy` to call it.